# Controller level security in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, controller

First time developing an angular app and I'm wondering what is the right way to have a route/controller level security. I basically want to restrict user to some app parts and have this requirement:

1. Forbid access certain routes if the user is not logged, redirect to login if user is not logged, if user is logged access that page.
2. Forbid access certain routes based on users fields, so for example if user has `verified: false` object field or some other way to hold the user data, then redirect user to the verification page. If user has `verified: true` allow access to the page.

How I though to do this would be, to make a service which will have method `verified()` and return the right value for the user, I would use the service in the controller, and this method to manually redirect based on the above requirements. My concern is a security of course, but also not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Almost all approaches can be easily 'hacked' from the console, or Grease/Tampermonkey, the one won't even need to tamper JS assets. I don't think it is appropriate to talk about 'security' in the context of client app, especially the parts of it that are not backed up by server side.

Answer (score 1):

For example in the `run` block:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var access_denied = [
            (toState.access === 'public'),
            (toState.access === 'protected'),
            (toState.access === 'private')];

        // example restriction
        if (accedd_denied[1] || accedd_denied[2]) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
```

Example router state:

```
state('login', {
    url: '/user/login',
    controller: 'UserController',
    access: 'public',
})
```

Comment: thanks for your response. What if I have more than one access. Here is what I mean, let's say protected is not accessible to the users who are not registered, and private is not accessible to users who are not verified. How would you put both restrictions on a route?